# Is there an elliptic curve over a number field with a point of order 64 and Mordell-Weil rank zero?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, torsion

It seems to me that there ought to be elliptic curves over number fields with arbitrarily large torsion subgroups but Mordell-Weil rank zero.  But I'll settle for a point of order 64.   Does anyone know that such things must exist?

Comment: One strategy is to find an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with full 2-torsion and rank $0$, then consider its $64$-torsion field $K_{64}$. Since there’s no reason for $E$ to have a non-torsion rational point over $K_{64}$ other than luck, at least for some $E$ the rank will stay $0$ over $K_{64}$. The choice of $E$ to have full 2-torsion over $\mathbb{Q}$ is simply to reduce the degree of $K_{64}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which minimizes the chances $E$ will pick up new points.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Don't we expect the average rank to increase with number field degree?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser I am actually not sure what to believe on that front. I am not sure if the Katz-Sarnak conjecture extends to arbitrary number fields (that is, if one fixes a number field $K$, and one orders elliptic curves over $K$ with respect to some reasonable height, whether the average rank should be $1/2$). Certainly for a fixed elliptic curve, one can find a tower of number fields $K_0 \subset K_1 \subset \cdots K_j \subset \cdots$ such that the rank of $E$ increases as $j$ increases, but usually the construction of such a tower is contrived.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao In any case, I'd expect that over a fixed number field and with elliptic curves ordered by some reasonable height, 100% of them should have rank 0 or 1. (Probably 50% of each, but since I haven't thought about it, maybe there's something that affects the sign of the functional equation to create unequal probabilities.) As for David's question, better probably to start with a curve with an 8-torsion point over Q. But even then, adjoining a 64-torsion point gives an extension of huge degree. Can we do a 2-descent in that field, even with the 2-torsion point to help?

Comment: I agree, if $E$ is a curve that is not coming from a lower field, having a $n$-torsion point, I bet chances are good that the rank is $0$ or $1$. On the other hand for certain Galois groups the parity results coming from Brauer relations impose rank growth. I have not thought about $n=64$. But in any case, all I can offer so far is speculation that this should exist, but no idea how to construct an example or how to verify it.

Comment: Thank you all for those comments!  I should have been clearer in my original question that I don't need an explicit example of a curve like this -- a proof that one exists will suffice.  The whole 50/50 thing for rank 0/1 has been in my head, but I haven't been able to make a rigorous proof out of it yet.

Comment: Also, the 64 thing is a minimal thing, not a crucial thing -- all I need is a torsion point of order at least 64.  If 2 is bad (because, let's be honest, it probably is!), then 3^k would be just fine.

Comment: I feel like there should be some world in which there's a family of curves, all with rational n-torsion, where the 0/1 50-50 applies, and I can pick my curve out from there.  But I can't figure out such a family.

Comment: @DavidMcKinnon The universal elliptic curve over $X_1(p^k)$ is precisely such a family. For each $K$ it has finitely many $K$-rational fibres. But how would you show that there is one of rank $0$?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Well, to be fair I don't know.  But my thought had been to see if anyone  had proven an average rank bound that would apply, so that some reasonable number of those curves would have to have rank zero.  It is definitely a problem that the family is high genus, so that the field of definition of the curves veers all over the place.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but an idea how one might get an answer with quite a bit of work. I am not too confident that I have not overlooked something.

Let $p$ be a prime and $k>1$. I am aiming to construct an elliptic curve $E$ over a number field $K$ with an $p^k$-torsion point in $E(K)$ but $E(K)$ has rank $0$.

Start with an elliptic curve $E$ with complex multiplication over some small field. Let $H$ be the field of definition of $E$ where the endomorphism ring has rank $2$. Discard $E$ if $E(H)$ is not of rank $0$. Now the extension $L/H$ adjoining the full $p^k$-torsion to $E$ is an abelian extension. There is a prime-to-$p$ extension $K/H$ such that $L/K$ is a product of two cyclic groups of $p$-power order. This sits inside the $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$-extension of $K$. One can now use the $2$-variable $p$-adic $L$-function and the main conjecture in Iwasawa theory to bound the rank of $E(L)$ from above. There is one sub-extension in which the Heegner points (from that curve $E$ itself) will force the rank to grow and that is linked to the issue with root numbers, but with some luck one can show that there is a point $P$ of order $p^k$ and $E(H(P))$ has rank $0$.

I hope there is enough results in Iwasawa theory for elliptic curves with complex multiplication that one could use this to work for odd primes $p$. For $p^k=64$, it may well be that one would have to work out first the detail of $2$-adic Iwasawa theory.

Maybe 49a1 over $\mathbb{Q}$ could work. We would have $H=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$, the rank of $E(H)$ is zero, and all $2$-torsion points are $H$-rational.

This relies on $E$ having complex multiplication. Because of parity/root number I am sceptical that a similar procedure should work for a curve without cm.

Comment: This sounds neat!  I will have to improve my Iwasawa fu to try it out, but that's a worthy cause in itself.